# Git keeps failing to pull from upstream on server

Tags: git, ssh

Whenever I ssh into my VPS I always have to run through a slew of commands in order to get my git repo to fetch changes from upstream. Sometimes I get lucky enough and it works. For the most part it gives me the not found error:

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I've added the following to the end of the `.bashrc` file on the machine:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent)"
eval "ssh-add /home/deploy/.ssh/id_rsa3"
```

When I ssh in I see the following output in the shell:

```
Agent pid 7974
Identity added: /home/deploy/.ssh/id_rsa3 (/home/deploy/.ssh/id_rsa3)
```

The fingerprint for the public key for `id_rsa3` matches the deploy key saved in the repo settings on Github. It never works unless I manually run the above commands. Why is that?

Comment: what (failing) commands are you trying to run? is your *normal* ssh-key (e.g. `~/.ssh/id_rsa`) connected to your github account? is your github account authorized to access the repo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se up the configuration in `~/.ssh/config` for you `ssh` to work with the key in non-standard location:

```
Host git-host-you-are-using-to-pull-from
  IdentityFile /home/deploy/.ssh/id_rsa3
```